# IIS Smooth Streaming

Tags: iis, streaming, smoothing

Hope someone can help out here. I have been trying out the IIS Smooth Streaming for many weeks. But without much success.

**On-demand Smooth Streaming**

- No problems with streaming on-demand clips on LAN
- No problems with streaming on-demand clips across the web

**Live streaming using file source**

- No problems with live streaming a file on LAN
- Cannot live stream a file across the web
  - Initiated a publishing point using AWS-EC2
  - Connected Encoder Pro to publishing point
  - Publishing point never gets past "Starting"

**Live streaming using live webcam**

- Slight problem with live streaming from my webcam on LAN
  - 10 seconds lag
  - After like 20 seconds, silverlight client hangs and stops requesting for chunks
  - HTTP 412 - precondition failed
  - Only way to rectify is to refresh the browser

- Cannot live stream from webcam across the web
  - Initiated a publish point using AWS-EC2
  - Connected Encoder Pro to publishing point
  - Publishing point never gets past "Starting"

**Things I have tried to rectify network problems**

- Connecting my laptop directly to the gateway, rather than through a router
- Shutting down Windows firewall on laptop
- Initiating a AWS-EC2 with no firewall
- WireShark indicates HTTP404 and HTTP501 error when "connecting" to the publishing point from the encoder

**My LAN specs**

- Running Encoder, and IIS Streaming Server on Boot Camp MacBook Pro, i7, 2.2GHz, 4GB RAM
- Running Silverlight Client on i5, 2.53GHz, 4GB RAM
- Output Stream: Default configurations for H.264 IIS Smooth Streaming Low Bandwidth

Answer (score 2):

To test streaming stuff you really need to use separate PCs as the streamer/encoder, transport server and client. Or at least start off that way. You are asking a bit too much out of that macbook pro there, especially when it comes to I/O.